# An invalid value is passed to a function dynamically loaded from a shared library

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries, dlopen

Im getting function dynamically from shared library on android 4.4 /system/lib/libgui.so

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <link.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define LOGI(...) \
  ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "screencast::", __VA_ARGS__))
#define LOGE(...) \
  ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "screencast::", __VA_ARGS__))

typedef void* (*getBuiltInDisplay_t)(int32_t);

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_screencast_1lib_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject) {
    LOGI("Loading libgui...");

    void *handle = dlopen("/system/lib/libgui.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {
        LOGE("Cannot load library: %s", dlerror());
        return env->NewStringUTF("error while loading system library");
    }

    LOGI("Loading symbol getBuiltInDisplay...");

    dlerror();
    getBuiltInDisplay_t getBuiltInDisplay = (getBuiltInDisplay_t) dlsym(handle, "_ZN7android21SurfaceComposerClient17getBuiltInDisplayEi");
    const char *dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if (dlsym_error) {
        LOGE("Cannot load symbol: %s", dlsym_error);
        dlclose(handle);
        return env->NewStringUTF("error while loading system function");
    }

    LOGI("Calling getBuiltInDisplay...");
    getBuiltInDisplay(0);

    LOGI("Closing library...");
    dlclose(handle);

    return env->NewStringUTF("success!!");
}
```

and getting this in the logs

```
...
04-26 17:45:12.623 D/dalvikvm( 6659): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
04-26 17:45:12.633 I/screencast::( 6659): Loading libgui...
04-26 17:45:12.633 I/screencast::( 6659): Loading symbol getBuiltInDisplay...
04-26 17:45:12.633 I/screencast::( 6659): Calling getBuiltInDisplay...
04-26 17:45:12.633 E/SurfaceFlinger(  175): getDefaultDisplay: id=1076775671 is not a valid default display id
04-26 17:45:12.633 F/libc    ( 6659): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6659 (.screencast_lib)
04-26 17:45:12.693 F/libc    ( 6739): Fatal signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x00001a53 (code=0), thread 6739 (sh)
...
```

Also i found [this implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-o-mr1-iot-release-1.0.0/services/surfaceflinger/SurfaceFlinger_hwc1.cpp#316) of getBuiltInDisplay static method.

```cpp
sp<IBinder> SurfaceFlinger::getBuiltInDisplay(int32_t id) {
    if (uint32_t(id) >= DisplayDevice::NUM_BUILTIN_DISPLAY_TYPES) {
        ALOGE("getDefaultDisplay: id=%d is not a valid default display id", id);
        return NULL;
    }
    return mBuiltinDisplays[id];
}
```

So, as I understand it, for some reason, the 0 value that I pass to the function is shown as a random value (1076775671 for this case, but it's random almost every time)

Comment: That's not a free function you're calling. It's a (non-static) member function of the `SurfaceComposerClient` class. So it expects a pointer to a `SurfaceComposerClient` instance to be passed to it somehow.

Comment: @Michael but it is defined as static in [headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-o-mr1-iot-release-1.0.0/libs/gui/include/gui/SurfaceComposerClient.h#122)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As @Michael said, it's not a static class method and needs to be passed a pointer. So I allocate some memory and pass a pointer as the first argument.

```cpp
typedef void* (*getBuiltInDisplay_t)(void*, int32_t);

// ...
    LOGI("Calling getBuiltInDisplay...");
    void *surfaceComposerClientInstance = malloc(1024);
    getBuiltInDisplay(surfaceComposerClientInstance, 0);
    free(surfaceComposerClientInstance);
// ...
```

And it works!